# item row total not updated in observer

Tags: cart, price, event-observer, magento-1, totals

I'm using checkout_cart_product_add_after event.

I have requirement like this
[Tier Prices for Specific Increments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/tier-prices-for-specific-increments)

I have written following code in my observer.

But row total is not updated in cart page.But in system.log its giving updated value.Thanks in advance.please let me know if you need any clarification.

Here Specific increment=3;

```
    class Exinent_Customprice_Model_Observer {
                public function customprice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

                     $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
                        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }             
                 if (($item->getQty() % 3) == 0)
                  {
                  $custom_price=5;
                  $item->setCustomPrice($custom_price); 
                  $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
                  $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);                           
                  }
                 else
                 {
                  $custom_price=5;
                  $rem=(int)(($item->getQty())/3);
                  $rowsubtotal=($rem)*(3)*($custom_price)+($item->getQty() % 3)*($item->getProduct()->getPrice()); 

                Mage::log($rowsubtotal);
                $item->setRowTotal($rowsubtotal);
                Mage::log($item->getRowTotal());
                 }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkout_cart_product_add_after` is triggered after the quote has already been saved. Try `sales_quote_product_add_after` instead, which is triggered in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::addProduct()`.

The event has one parameter, `items` with an array of quote items that have been generated from this product. For simple products it is always one item. For complex products (bundle, configurable), the first array item is always the parent (i.e. the main product). So you get your item like this:

```
item = $observer->getItems()[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write `$item->save();` after setting custom price to save the quote item custom price.